# Телефонувати чи дзвонити?

Tags: вибір-слова, дієслова

У [СУМі](http://sum.in.ua/s/dzvonyty) знаходжу:

> **ДЗВОНИТИ,** дзвоню, дзвониш, недок.
>
> 2. Викликати до телефону дзвінком телефонного апарата; говорити по телефону. — Дзвонили ви до Русевича? — спитав Петров .. — Двічі дзвонив (Юрій Шовкопляс, Інженери, 1956, 58); [Надія:] А мій Гордій теж приїхав? [Ромодан:] Скоро буде, дзвонив мені... (Олександр Корнійчук, II, 1955, 283).
>
> **ТЕЛЕФОНУВАТИ**, ую, уєш, недок. і док.
>
> 1. Викликати до телефону дзвінком телефонного апарата. Дивуючися, хто ж це може тут їй уночі телефонувати, Сахно взяла трубку (Юрій Смолич, I, 1958, 84); — Мушу бути в канцелярії, ану ж хтось телефонуватиме (Гашек, Пригоди.. Швейка, перекл. Масляка, 1958, 351).
> 2. Повідомляти про що-небудь по телефону. Телефоную в Москву. — Синку, море підходить до груші (Олександр Довженко, III, 1960, 509).

[СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/telefonuvaty)

У [Словнику синонімів](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%B4%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8) також знаходимо:

> **ТЕЛЕФОНУВА́ТИ** (викликати для розмови телефоном), **ДЗВОНИ́ТИ.** - Док.: зателефонува́ти, протелефонува́ти, подзвони́ти.

Однак, на сайті [Оnlinecorrector](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8/) знаходжу:

> Замініть дієслово **дзвонити, подзвонити, передзвонити,** якщо мовиться про телефонний дзвінок, на стилістично кращий варіант: **телефонувати, потелефонувати, перетелефонувати.**

Отже, чи буде нормативно вживати *подзвони мені*, чи є це правило десь офіційно поміщене.

Comment: Незрозмуло, навіщо використовувати запозичене *телефонувати*, коли є своє *дзвонити*? Я б іще й *телефон* замінив на якійсь *далекослух*:)

Comment: @Yola, _телефонувати_ точніше. _Дзвонити_ можна й у дзвін. Фактично, _дзвонити_ — робити будь-який шум, не обов'язково адресний і не обов'язково в ролі запрошення до сеансу дистанційної передачі даних. Тобто я не кажу, що _телефонувати_ правильніше, по-моєму, вони обидва підходять, але все-таки значення слова _телефонувати_ вужче.

Answer (score 1):

Все ж таки варто звернути увагу на те, що ОнлайнКоректор вказує, що "**Не рекомендовано**" вживати слово "дзвонити" у значенні: "Викликати до телефону дзвінком телефонного апарата", однак все ж його вживання можливе. А згідно до цієї [статті](http://kulturamovy.univ.kiev.ua/KM/pdfs/Magazine59-41.pdf) - слово "дзвонити" частіше вживається у розмовній мові, так само як і "стелефонуймося".

Також [Лінгвістичний портал](http://www.mova.info/article.aspx?l1=198&DID=2736) закликає до того, щоб вживати дієслово "телефонувати", тому, гадаю, що все ж краще уникати вживання слова "дзвонити" скажімо у творах ЗНО.